# About the $dirty property and getting only modified fields in a form

Tags: forms, angularjs

I have a form with few fields and I'm trying to get modified fields only.
Here is what I got so far (simplified version) :

```
<form name="formTicket">

                        <div class="item title">
                            <label for="category-assignation"><?php echo T::_("Assignation :")?></label>
                            <textarea type="text" name="assignation" cols="50" rows="4" id="category-assignation" data-ng-model="ticket.assignation"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item title">
                            <input id="save" type="submit" value="Save" data-ng-click="saveTicketInfo()"  />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

In my controller.js, I have :

```
$scope.saveTicketInfo =  function() {
                    console.info($scope.ticket);
                    console.info($scope.formTicket);
                    //Query to my service to save the data
                    Category.saveInfo.query({data: $scope.ticket});
                };
```

Prior to AngularJs, I would save my fields in an array at the loading of my form and compare their values with the new values posted. I could still do this but I'm looking for an AngularJs approach.

I've been trying to use the $dirty property of each field and only send to my services those with "true" value but this behavior is not suitable for me : if the defaut value for my field is "test" and the user modify the input to  "test2" and modify it back to "test" and post it, $dirty will be true (even if the value has not really changed).

Is there any convenient and optimal way to achieve what I want ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Right, $dirty doesn't determine if the user editted a field then corrected it back to the orginal value - it just sets a flag stating that the user used that field.  I've had the same problem and wish it compared original values as well.  If your form is not to large you can `$watch` the particular fields for changes and then compare them to an original copy and if they are the same then reset the `$dirty` property of the field.

Comment: Just do a deep compare of the two versions before posting.